# How to render HTML and CSS from textboxes on webpage into a

Tags: html, css, angularjs, iframe

Essentially I'm trying to create a mini-clone of JSFiddle.

That is, I want to allow my users to type some HTML and CSS and see the rendered result in another area of the screen. I'm also looking to use AngularJS.

Does anyone have any advice or experience on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much Javascript you know/want to use, but you could create 3 frames, for the HTML, CSS and output. In the HTML and CSS frames, put an input text area. Then on the "run" button click, change the inner HTML of the output to the content of the html (within HTML tags) and the css (within Style tags).

Answer (score 1):

*(I drafted this before you made the Angular edit, but you can use jQuery with Angular.)*

You can do this within a single page, if you're somewhat careful:

1. You can have only one `body` tag on a page. So any `body` styles should apply to the container only, *not* to the document body.  The code below handles this by changing a `body` tag style to a `.body` class style, which applies to a `div` within the container with class `body`.
2. Any other styles should also apply to the container's children only.  The code below handles this by first appending the "style sheet" textarea to the container, then iterating through the style rules and prepending the container's ID to each selector.  (The original rules are deleted and the new rules are inserted.)

The code below works in IE9+ and modern browsers.  **[Working Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dwfjsj7b/12/)**

---

```
<div>
  <textarea placeholder="Enter HTML here"></textarea>
  <textarea placeholder="Enter CSS here"> </textarea>
</div>

<div id="Render"></div>

$('div').first()
  .keyup(function() {
    $('#Render').html(
      '<style>'+$('div:first textarea:not(:first)').val()+'</style>'+
      '<div class="body">'+$('div:first textarea:first').val()+'</div>'
    );
    var ss= document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length-1],
        rules= ss.cssRules;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < rules.length ; i++) {
      var rule= '#Render '+rules[i].selectorText
                .replace('body','.body')
                .split(',').join(', #Render')+
                '{'+rules[i].cssText.split('{')[1];
      ss.deleteRule(i);
      ss.insertRule(rule, i);
    }      
  })
  .keyup();
```

Comment: Thanks - awesome answer. Sorry for not including the Angular part at the beginning. Nonetheless, this is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary file with the CSS and HTML provided and then use a Frame to view that file in another section of the page